# Opening line for business email before christmas

Tags: email, letter-writing

Can I use the below opening line for an email to a client

"Hi XYZ

Hope you are doing good. I'm sure you must be looking forward to the Christmas now.

Did you get chance to look into blah blah blah !!

"

Comment: I think it's better to add some seasonal greetings as well. Now it sounds a bit rough like "I'm sure that your thoughts are already about Christmas but that doesn't matter, let's return to our business"

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for the site. The Workplace might be better.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the general tone, it totally depends on your client, and your relationship with them.   If you are a lawyer and they're currently in prison awaiting sentencing, or if they don't celebrate Christmas, it might not be received well.

There are also some errors:

- "Hope you are doing good" should be "I hope you are doing well" or "I hope you are well." *
- "You must be looking forward to Christmas" would be better. Definitely not 'The Christmas' and 'I'm sure you must be' is redundant.

*Not sure if this is acceptable in American English, but in British English, 'hope you are doing good' is wrong.